# Ember Integration Test Doesn't See the DOM

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, ember-cli, qunit

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from '../../helpers/start-app';

var App;

module('Integration | Authentication | Abilities', {
  integration: true,
  setup() {
    App = startApp();
  },
  teardown() {
    Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('Only SuperUsers, Researchers and AccountHolders can see messages', function(assert) {
  visit('/');
  assert.equal(find('div').text(), 'fsfsfd');
});
```

This is an integration test I'm trying to get working so I can test basic user interaction in our ember-cli app. The problem is that this simple test does only returns empty strings whenever I search the DOM. It is not hitting an unauthorized page or anything it's just returning nothing from any testHelpers. `currentURL`, `currentPath` return undefined.

Am I missing something absolutely fundamental in my understanding of how integration tests work?

I'm trying to test how ember-can gives and denies permissions to users based on their title. However, I may as well just be testing whether or not the logo shows up in the right corner because I can't see anything on the page at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is that tests are asynchronous. Transitions involve promises (typically loading models) so you need to wait for the `visit` to complete. You can use the `andThen` helper:

```
test('Only SuperUsers, Researchers and AccountHolders can see messages', function(assert) {
  visit('/');

  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(find('div').text(), 'fsfsfd');
  });
});
```

[Here's more info in the guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/testing/acceptance/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting because it turns out the problem was the way our website had been set up with a rootURL. I had to put this line inside our startApp.js file: `setResolver(Ember.DefaultResolver.create({ namespace: "/cli/ea/" }));`

It looks like the resolver was taking me to localhost:4201/ which is not actually going to be used because we are proxying from rails (which is localhost:3000). Therefore, nothing was coming back from any DOM interaction because there was no route and no template set. currentURL and other helpers returning undefined I guess was the only piece that was unusual in hindsight.